# Ethereum Wallet / Mist v0.8.8 keeps shutting down and therefore not syncing

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, bug

I hope someone can help.

I have Ethereum Wallet v0.8.8 and Mist v0.8.8 (windoes 64bit). They open OK, and looks like they start to sync with the blockchain. However, after 30-60 seconds they **always** shut down automatically.

I've tried opening Mist on it's own, and Ethereum Wallet on its own. Same problem with each one.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: if i open it, it shows up in task manager and then after 5secs goes away so it shut downs automaticlly and doesnt even show any window